# passing a utf8 encoded string to web service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Can I pass a UTF8 encoded string to a web service?

**UPDATED:**

```
Function EncodeToUTF(ByVal toEncode As String) As String
    Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding()

    Dim encodedBytes As Byte() = utf8.GetBytes(toEncode)
    Dim returnValue As String = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes)
    returnValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnValue)
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

And then decode this on the web server?  The issue is that the XML Web Service parser is striping out CRs from my string.

Then on server side to decode:

```
Function DecodeFromUTF8(ByVal encodedData As String) As String
    Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding()

    Dim returnValue As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedData)
    Dim encodedDataAsBytes As Byte() = utf8.GetBytes(returnValue)

    returnValue = utf8.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes)

    Return returnValue
End Function
```

The returnValue here is still encoded.

Comment: Because you have not decoded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL encode your string/message. Messages must be URL Encoded before being sent to a webservice as they contain special characters.

```
Function EncodeToUTF(ByVal toEncode As String) As String
    Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding()

    Dim encodedBytes As Byte() = utf8.GetBytes(toEncode)
    Dim returnValue As String = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes)

    '' URL encode your string before pushing it to a web service
    returnValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnValue)

    Return returnValue
End Function
```

And, on the other server side, use the following to decode your encoded string:

```
Dim decodedUrl As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedUrl)
```

Hopefully, this will solve your issue.

Comment: Ok then I guess that I need to do some thing like that on the web server to UrlDecode?

Comment: Didn't work. I'll update the OP with server side decode shortly. UPDATED OP.